# How can I retrieve a collection property using criteria Api

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I want to retrieve a collection property using criteria

```
   public class A {  
       private Collection<B> property  
       // getters and setters
   }  
   public class B {
      private int status
      // getters and setters
   }
```

My criteria code is as follows:

```
Criteria cr = getSession().createCriteria(A.class)     
cr.createAlias("property", "prop")
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("prop.status", status));
cr.setProjection(Projections.property("prop"));
cr.list();
```

It's obvious this code doesn't work I wanted to simply demonstrate my intentions. I know how to achieve this using HQL, but I have to use Criteria API. Is what I am aiming for even possible using Criteria ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately what I want to achieve is not possible with Hibernate Criteria. If someone needs something like that you should create a namedQuery , as awfull as that migh be to you or just use hql.

Peter

Answer (score 0):

What wrong with this solution ?

```
Criteria cr = getSession().createCriteria(B.class);
 cr.add(Restrictions.eq("status", status));
 cr.list();
```

Comment: I need A.property collection not just all B instances in the DB with a certain status. I need all B connected to A with a provided status. Unfortunately B has no references to A (I wouldn't have ask a question if that were the case), just the A 0..* B connection

Regards,
Peter