# Criteria query containing a collection valued property

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

Is it possible (and if so how) to create a criteria query that results in a tuple or array of which some elements are collections from a collection valued property?

Given an entity `Dummy` which has a `List<SubEntities>` with name `subs`

```
class Dummy {
    String name;
    List<SubEntity> subs;
}

class SubEntity {
    // some attributes
}
```

I want a criteria API query which results in something with the structure

Tuple>

An `Array` instead of a `Tuple` would be fine, same for an `Array` or similar for `List`.

I tried the following:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Object[]> q = cb.createQuery(Object[].class);
Root<DummyEntityWithCollection> root = q.from(DummyEntityWithCollection.class);
Join<Object, Object> subs = root.join("subs");
q.select(cb.array(root.get("name"), subs));

List<Object[]> list = em.createQuery(q).getResultList();
```

But the `Object[]`s contained in `list` have as the second element `SubEntity`s instead of `List<SubEntity>`.

This one fails in the same way:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Tuple> q = cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<DummyEntityWithCollection> root = q.from(DummyEntityWithCollection.class);
Join<Object, Object> subs = root.join("subs");
q.multiselect(root.get("name"), subs);

List<Tuple> list = em.createQuery(q).getResultList();
```

This variant

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Object[]> q = cb.createQuery(Object[].class);
Root<DummyEntityWithCollection> root = q.from(DummyEntityWithCollection.class);
q.select(cb.array(root.get("name"), root.get("subs")));

List<Object[]> list = em.createQuery(q).getResultList();
```

Doesn't work at all and results in an invalid SQL statement with a single `.` as one select column (at least for Hibernate and HSQLDB).

The question [How can I retrieve a collection property using criteria Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608220/how-can-i-retrieve-a-collection-property-using-criteria-api) seems to indicate that it is not possible but it is based on Hibernate and I would like to get a JPA based answer. Especially an answer pointing out the section of the JPA spec that makes it clear that this is not possible would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[JPQL defines](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf) the select clause in section 4.8 as

```
select_clause ::= SELECT [DISTINCT] select_item {, select_item}*
select_item ::= select_expression [[AS] result_variable]
select_expression ::= single_valued_path_expression | scalar_expression | aggregate_expression | identification_variable | OBJECT(identification_variable) | constructor_expression
```

so you can see that multi-valued expressions are not selectable in JPQL.

Criteria is simply a way to create a query using an API and objects. See JPA spec chapter 6.1:

> The semantics of criteria queries are designed to reflect those of Java Persistence query
>   language queries.

So it's reasonable to assume the same constraint applies to the Criteria API.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I added some explicit references and a link.